# Why bmp image displayed as wrong color with plt.imshow of matplotlib on IPython-notebook?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

There is a bmp image just as shown the first picture bellow, and its information is list as the second picture bellow. But when display with plt.imshow() function of matplotlib on IPython-notebook, it has the wrong color, just as the third picture bellow. So can I know the reason?
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

The original file has shared at dropbox https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26518813/test2.bmp

And the code to show image on IPython-notebook is:

```
%pylab inline --no-import-all
from PIL import Image
plt.imshow(Image.open("./test/test2.bmp"))
```

Comment: Can you include the original .bmp and all your code? So we can download and try with it...

Comment: @GM the file and the code has pasted above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happen because you are actually plotting the image as matrix with matplotlib.pyplot. Matplotlib doesn't support `.bmp`natively so I think there are some error with the default cmap. In your specific case you have a grayscale image. So in fact you can change the color map to grayscale with `cmap="gray"`.

```
from PIL import Image
img= Image.open(r'./test/test2.bmp')
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray',vmin=0,vmax=255)
```

Note you have to set vmin and vmax if you want to reproduce the same luminance of your original image otherwise I think python by default will stretch to min max the values.
This is a solution without importing PIL:

```
img=matplotlib.image.imread(r'/Users/giacomo/Downloads/test2.bmp')
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray',vmin=0,vmax=255)
```

Alternatively you can use PIL to show the image or you can convert your image to a `.png` before.

If you want show the image with `PIL.Image` you can use this:

```
from PIL import Image
img= Image.open( r'./test/test2.bmp')
img.show()
```

**Note if you are using I-Python Notebook the image is shown in a new external window**

Another option is to change the mode of the image to `'P'` (Palette encoding: one byte per pixel, with a palette of class ImagePalette translating the pixels to colors). With `.convert` and then plot the image with matplotlib `plt.imshow`:

```
convertedimg=img.convert('P')
plt.imshow(convertedimg)
```

[image]

Comment: on my IPython-notebook, img.show() cant get anything showed on browser.

Comment: But the image is distorted. Thanks!

Comment: @Honghe.Wu This is not my case (see image) what browser and operating system are you using have you try with python shell? What's happen?

Comment: Ubuntu Server runs IPython-notebook as backend. Thanks.

Comment: @Honghe.Wu I've added the last solution I have found I hope it helps! Thank you! Nice question I hope someone could add some information.

Comment: For reference, adding the line `%matplotlib inline` after importing matplotlib works too. 
Using `.show()` is still useful as it avoids printing something like `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10b49b450>]` before the actual image.