# plot several image files in matplotlib subplots

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to create a matrix subplot and display each BMP files, from a directory, in a different subplot, but I cannot find the appropriate solution for my problem, could somebody helping me?.

This the code that I have:

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob

bmps = glob('*trace*.bmp')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3)

for arch in bmps:
    i = Image.open(arch)
    iar = np.array(i)
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            axes[i, j].plot(iar)
            plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

I am having the following error after executing:

[image]

Answer (score 40):

natively matplotlib only supports PNG images, see http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html

then the way is always *read the image - plot the image*

*read image*

```
 img1 = mpimg.imread('stinkbug1.png')
 img2 = mpimg.imread('stinkbug2.png')
```

*plot image* (2 subplots)

```
 plt.figure(1)
 plt.subplot(211)
 plt.imshow(img1)

 plt.subplot(212)
 plt.imshow(img2)
 plt.show()
```

follow the tutorial on http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html (because of the import libraries)

here is a thread on plotting bmps with matplotlib: [Why bmp image displayed as wrong color with plt.imshow of matplotlib on IPython-notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641822/why-bmp-image-displayed-as-wrong-color-with-plt-imshow-of-matplotlib-on-ipython)

Comment: Ralf, thanks for your reply. If I understood your answer I need to change the format from BMP to PNG and then run again my code? You did no mention about my code, If i have PNG instead BMP do you think that my code is going to run? Thanks again.

Comment: for a first try i would keep it simpler like in http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#pyplot-tutorial and the post above. if it works you can add more sophisticated functionality

Answer (score 6):

The bmp has three color channels, plus the height and width, giving it a shape of (h,w,3). I believe plotting the image gives you an error because the plot only accepts two dimensions. You could grayscale the image, which would produce a matrix of only two dimensions (h,w).

Without knowing the dimensions of the images, you could do something like this:

```
for idx, arch in enumerate(bmps):
    i = idx % 3 # Get subplot row
    j = idx // 3 # Get subplot column
    image = Image.open(arch)
    iar_shp = np.array(image).shape # Get h,w dimensions
    image = image.convert('L') # convert to grayscale
    # Load grayscale matrix, reshape to dimensions of color bmp
    iar = np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(iar_shp[0], iar_shp[1])
    axes[i, j].plot(iar)
 plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
 plt.show()
```

Comment: Brian, If I run it with your suggestions seems that the process goes into a infinity loop (Memory Error)

Comment: I think there was a problem with your two nested loops. See the revised code snippet above.

Comment: Hello, Brian, after several trials I can't obtain just the result that I would like to have, I change the format files to JPG's and now my list "bmps" contains my JPG's files after I run your suggestion I get the following message: IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2