# Show OpenCV image in matplotlib's subplots

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am having troubles in showing OpenCV images in matplotlib's subplot

```
#Read random images from multiple directories
import random
animals = os.listdir('signs/train')
sample_images = []
for a in animals:
  dirname = 'signs/train/' + a
  files = random.sample(os.listdir(dirname), 5)
  files = [dirname + '/' + im for im in files]
  sample_images.extend(files)

del files, dirname,   animals
print(sample_images)

# Output: ['signs/train/rooster/00000327.jpg', 'signs/train/rooster/00000329.jpg', 'signs/train/rooster/00000168.jpg', ...,  'signs/train/rooster/00000235.jpg', 'signs/train/rooster/00000138.jpg']

#Read using OpenCV and show in matplotlib's subplots

fig, ax = plt.subplots(12, 5,figsize=(15,15), sharex=True)
for idx, si in enumerate(sample_images):
  i = idx % 5 # Get subplot row
  j = idx // 5 # Get subplot column
  image = cv2.imread(si)
  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
  image = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64))
  ax[i, j].plot(image)
plt.show()
```

I have checked that each image is successfully loaded and resized using opencv, but I don't know why I keep getting the following error when I plot them on `matplotlib`'s `subplot`.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-56-38cc921c1724> in <module>()
     10   #image = Image.open(si)
     11   #print(type(image))
---> 12   ax[i, j].plot(image)
     13 plt.show()

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    271         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    272             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have "
--> 273                              "shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
    274 
    275         if x.ndim == 1:

ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (64,) and (64, 64, 3)
```

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that I have tried testing on one image, and it works (even if it is JPG format and still uses RGB channels)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `ax.plot()` incorrectly as it only plots y versus x data. The correct function is `plt.imshow()` which is matplotlib's built in function to display image data. The example below works and can be extended for your purposes.

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image1 = cv.imread('image1.jpg')
image2 = cv.imread('image2.jpg')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(image1)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(image2)
```

Comment: For detail, it is not entirely wrong. Ax should be use 'imshow' instead of 'plot' and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692507/plot-several-image-files-in-matplotlib-subplots/3569269), which discusses images in matplotlib subplots, it seems that only PNG file types are supported.

See also the [image tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/images.html) linked in the same.

I believe the error is caused because the subplot only accepts two-dimensional images, and since the JPG has three color channels, matplotlib isn't sure which information to map to x & y dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The intention of `plot` should only be apply to 2d data (eg. Grayscale image), when you add in a 3d image, you should apply it with `imshow` instead. Therefore, all you need to do is replacing `ax[i, j].plot(image)` with `ax[i, j].imshow(image)` and everything will be fine.